# PHP - Files won't download to the server

Tags: php, download, request

I've been getting into some problems where whenever I try to get the request of downloading the items images to the server it doesn't work. It seems to get the items to display the penguin with the items, but that's only cause the the images are there. The images are downloaded to a path called `paper/images/%size%/%itemid%`. I'm not sure if the permissions aren't correct or what it just displays a empty page as shown here. http://api.frosty.us/avatar/?id=1. As you can see here the items are here http://api.frosty.us/avatar/paper/image/88/9.png it gets the users color, head, neck, body, flag, photo, face, etc. Then it builds it up like a doll.

Here is the my code

```
<?php


function downloadPapers($itemId, $paperSizes = array(60, 88, 120, 600)){
    foreach($paperSizes as $paperSize){
        $avatarPaperUri = sprintf('paper/image/%d/%d.png', $paperSize, $itemId);
        $avatarPaperUrl = 'http://mobcdn.clubpenguin.com/game/items/images/' . $avatarPaperUri;
        $paperCurl = curl_init($avatarPaperUrl);
        curl_setopt($paperCurl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
        curl_setopt($paperCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $imageData = curl_exec($paperCurl);
        $statusCode = curl_getinfo($paperCurl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($paperCurl);
        if($statusCode == 200){
            file_put_contents($avatarPaperUri, $imageData);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
function cachePaper($itemId, $paperSize){
    $downloadStatus = downloadPapers($itemId);

    if($downloadStatus !== false){
        $paperImage = imagecreatefrompng(sprintf('paper/image/%d/%d.png', $paperSize, $itemId));
        return $paperImage;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
function returnPaperResource($itemId, $paperSize = 120){
    $avatarUnbiasUri = sprintf('paper/image/%d/%d.png', $paperSize, $itemId);
    $paperImage = file_exists($avatarUnbiasUri) ? imagecreatefrompng($avatarUnbiasUri) : cachePaper($itemId, $paperSize);

    return $paperImage;
}
$validPaperSizes = array(60, 88, 120, 600);
$defaultPaperSize = 120;
if(isset($_GET['id']) === false){
    die();
}
$playerSwid = $_GET['id'];
if(isset($_GET['size']) === false){
    $avatarPaperSize = 120;
} else {
    $avatarPaperSize = $_GET['size'];
}
if(is_dir("paper/image/60/") === false){
    mkdir("paper/image/60/", 0755, true);
}
if(is_dir("paper/image/88/") === false){
    mkdir("paper/image/88/", 0755, true);
}
if(is_dir("paper/image/120/") === false){
    mkdir("paper/image/120/", 0755, true);
}
if(is_dir("paper/image/600/") === false){
    mkdir("paper/image/600/", 0755, true);
}
if(!in_array($avatarPaperSize, $validPaperSizes)){
    $avatarPaperSize = $defaultPaperSize;
}
require 'configlinkhere';

try {
    $database = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db_host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db_name'], $config['db_user'], $config['db_pass']);
} catch(PDOException $pdoException){
    echo $pdoException->getMessage(), die();
}
$playerQuery = 'SELECT ID FROM `users` WHERE ID = :ID';
$playerStatement = $database->prepare($playerQuery);
$playerStatement->bindValue(':ID', $playerSwid);
$playerStatement->execute();
$rowCount = $playerStatement->rowCount();
$playerStatement->closeCursor();
if($rowCount < 1){
    echo 'Player doesn\'t exist', die();
}
$clothingQuery = 'SELECT head, face, neck, body, hand, feet, photo, flag, colour FROM `users` WHERE ID = :ID';
$clothingStatement = $database->prepare($clothingQuery);
$clothingStatement->bindValue(':ID', $playerSwid);
$clothingStatement->execute();
$playerClothing = $clothingStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$clothingStatement->closeCursor();
header('Content-type: image/png');
$colorResource = returnPaperResource($playerClothing['colour'], $avatarPaperSize);
unset($playerClothing['colour']);
if($playerClothing['photo'] != 0){
    $imageResource = returnPaperResource($playerClothing['photo'], $avatarPaperSize);
    if($imageResource === false) {
        $imageResource = $colorResource;
    } else {
        imagecopyresampled($imageResource, $colorResource, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($imageResource), imagesy($imageResource), imagesx($colorResource), imagesy($colorResource));
    }
} else {
    $imageResource = $colorResource;
}
unset($playerClothing['photo']);
foreach($playerClothing as $clothingPart => $itemId){
    if($itemId != 0){
        $clothingResource = returnPaperResource($itemId, $avatarPaperSize);
        if($clothingResource !== false) {
            imagecopyresampled($imageResource, $clothingResource, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($imageResource), imagesy($imageResource), imagesx($clothingResource), imagesy($clothingResource));
        }
    }
}
imagealphablending($imageResource, false);
imagesavealpha($imageResource, true);
imagepng($imageResource);
imagedestroy($imageResource);
unset($database);

?>
```

Comment: http://api.frosty.us/avatar/?id=1 its not empty have you tested if the file directory name is correct?

Comment: It is correct my problem is that it won't retrieve and download the files into the directory. I'm thinking that it's the permissions that it's set to "root root".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out the problem it was using the permission `root root` which it should've been using the permission `www-data www-data`